# compromise the solution of multi objective function in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, genetic

**I have two objective function, I optimized them in matlab using genetic algorithm multi objective function as the follow
f

```
unction [output]= multi_objective_function_2(input)**

x1 = input(1);     
x2 = input(2);    
x3 = input(3);    
x4 = input(4);    
x5 = input(5);    
x6 = input(6);    
x7 = input (7);   

f1 = -(1.0125*x1 + 14.8125*x2 + 1.3113*x3 + 0.783*x4 + 10.365*x5 + 2.435*x6 + 1.78*x7);   
f2 = -(3303*x1 + 7510*x2 + 41370*x3 + 1628*x4 + 23046*x5 + 5412*x6 + 58113*x7);           
output = [f1 f2];
end
```

```
 clear;
 clc;
tic
numberOfVariables = 7;
A = [-1 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1; 1715.78 5586.32 1654.93 1963.37 4414.64 6973.88 4416.31; -1.0125 -14.8125 -1.3113 -0.783 0 0 0];
b = [-3; -45; -2445; -71; -10402.5; -5201; -10402.5; 208000000; -3931];
Aeq = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 1 1 1];
beq = [26006.25; 26006.25];
LB = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
UB = [26006.25 26006.25 26006.25 26006.25 26006.25 26006.25 26006.25];
options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns',@gaplotpareto);
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = gamultiobj(@multi_objective_function_2,numberOfVariables,A,b,Aeq,beq,LB,UB,options);
disp('     x1        x2        x3         x4          x5         x6         x7  ');
disp(x)
disp('         F1      F2');
disp(fval)
disp(output)
fprintf('The number of points on the Pareto front was: %d\n', size(x,1));
toc
```

I want solution which make each of the two objective function to be achieve 50% of the solutioى

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. It is fairly hard to give a satisfactory answer to your question as you're asking it. Do you know what kind of answer you're looking for? A bit of formatting and a little clarification on your question might help. You might want to take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That being said, Can't you just test the output to check if they satisfy your condition?
Also, it looks like your two objective functions will only decrease when you increase your variables... so if I'm not mistaken the Pareto front will be along your domain wall... maybe it's easier to tackle it that way?